# Why SharePoint 2010 Calculated fields show in EditForm.aspx and newForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint, content-type

I have a list using content types that use 2 site columns that are calculated fields based on other site columns used in same content type.

The list made from it works fine and the New and edit forms do not show the calculated fields which make scene.

When I copy the list with ShareGate to other site collections, all the relevant site columns and content types are created but on some target sites, the new and edit form show the calculated fields. How is this even possible?
Is there an easy way to remove them from the form?

Answer (score 0):

Probably column settings have not been copied by ShareGate. Check if column settings are setted to Hidden:

[image]

(Source of image: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012_12_01_archive.html)